# Why does a segfault occur when accessing vtkRenderWindow's ```Interactor``` variable?

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I have an application that uses VTK 9.0 with QT 5.14.2, on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. It compiles just fine (using gcc) and most of the application works. However, when I try to create a vtkRenderWindow, it crashes with a segfault. Specifically, whenever my application tries to access or interact with the vtkRenderWindow object’s protected `Interactor` variable (declared in `vtkRenderWindow.h:754`).

`vtkRenderWindowInteractor* Interactor;`

Thus far, I’ve had it crashing with **(1)** `vtkRenderWindow::GetInteractor()`, **(2)** `vtkRenderWindow::SetInteractor()`, and **(3)** `vtkRenderWindow::MakeRenderWindowInteractor()`.

**(1)** To be more precise, the program crashes the moment it attempts to execute `vtkRenderWindow::GetInteractor()`. My code calling the VTK functions:

```
vtkRenderer* m_Ren1;
vtkRenderWindow* renwin;
Ui::vtkwindow_new *ui;
QVTKOpenGLStereoWidget* qVTK1;

m_Ren1 = vtkRenderer::New();
renwin = vtkRenderWindow::New();
renwin->AddRenderer(m_Ren1);
ui->qVTK1->setRenderWindow(renwin);

ui->qVTK1->renderWindow()->GetInteractor();
```

**(2)** When calling `vtkRenderWindow::SetInteractor()`, it crashes at `vtkRenderWindow.cxx:155`, at the line
`if (this->Interactor != rwi)`. I show the code I use below:

```
vtkRenderer* m_Ren1;
vtkRenderWindow* renwin;
Ui::vtkwindow_new *ui;
QVTKOpenGLStereoWidget* qVTK1;

m_Ren1 = vtkRenderer::New();
renwin = vtkRenderWindow::New();
renwin->AddRenderer(m_Ren1);
ui->qVTK1->setRenderWindow(renwin);

vtkRenderWindowInteractor* t1 = vtkRenderWindowInteractor::New();
ui->qVTK1->renderWindow()->SetInteractor(t1);
```

**(3)** When calling `vtkRenderWindow::MakeRenderWindowInteractor()`, it crashes at `vtkObjectFactory.cxx:438`, specifically when it calls the `strcmp` function.

```
if (this->OverrideArray[i].EnabledFlag &&
  strcmp(this->OverrideClassNames[i], vtkclassname) == 0)
```

Again, I show the code I use to test this below:

```
vtkRenderer* m_Ren1;
vtkRenderWindow* renwin;
Ui::vtkwindow_new *ui;
QVTKOpenGLStereoWidget* qVTK1;

m_Ren1 = vtkRenderer::New();
renwin = vtkRenderWindow::New();
renwin->AddRenderer(m_Ren1);
ui->qVTK1->setRenderWindow(renwin);
ui->qVTK1->renderWindow()->MakeRenderWindowInteractor();
```

Curiously, the program does not crash if I create a new RenderWindow as below, despite both `test` and `qVTK1->renderWindow()` being of type `vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow`. It does crash regardless of if I set `qVTK1->renderWindow()`'s interactor to `t1` or `t2`:

```
vtkRenderWindow* test = vtkRenderWindow::New();
vtkRenderWindowInteractor* t2 = test->GetInteractor();
vtkRenderWindowInteractor* t1 = vtkRenderWindowInteractor::New();
test->SetInteractor(t1);
ui->qVTK1->renderWindow()->SetInteractor(t1);
ui->qVTK1->renderWindow()->SetInteractor(t2);
```

If anyone has any idea why this occurs or how to deal with it, I would very much appreciate it. I've asked over on the VTK forums as well, but haven't received an answer after a week. I have not been able to find similar cases described anywhere. Given that all the crashes occur in the VTK library code, I am quite baffled as to what is causing it.

Thanks!

Comment: You should check the value of what `ui->qVTK1->renderWindow()` call returns. If it's a null pointer or a dangling one it explains the crashes you get.

Comment: Thanks @vahancho. It _was_ a null pointer, but the cause was rather nebulous. I've solved the issue, it was a QT problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! The problem actually came about from the QT side. `QVTKOpenGLRenderWindow` cannot deal with `vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow`, it requires `vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow`. But `vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow` cannot be created with `vtkRenderWindow::New()`. The solution is to declare the renderwindow wrapped in a `vtkNew<>` pointer:

```
    vtkRenderer* m_Ren1;
    vtkRenderWindow* renwin;
    QVTKOpenGLStereoWidget* qVTK1;

    m_Ren1 = vtkRenderer::New();

    vtkNew<vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow> rw;
    renwin = rw;

    renwin->AddRenderer(m_Ren1);
    ui->qVTK1->setRenderWindow(renwin);
```

This solves the problem with the interactor.